# how to get ctakes gui running while the ctakes-gui does not have any jsp file?

Tags: ctakes

I Have been following this instructions of ctakes GUI link here

https://community.i2b2.org/wiki/display/NLPCTAKES/NLP+cTakes+Home

I could not find any website that has ctakesgui.war

I thought it must be the same project in ctakes open source which is ctakes-gui

but this project ctakes-gui does not have any .jsp or .html files.

[image]

How can I get ctakes-gui work as this

[image]